# App crashes with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in android sometimes

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have an application made which draws a square on the screen. The user can move the square around, increase its width and height using his/her finger (touch events) etc etc. The user is also able to add any number of squares and move them separately.

The app works fine for most of the part but sometimes it crashes and gives this below error

```
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826): Process: com.example, PID: 24826
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:835)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:779)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.example.Square.isClicked(Square.java:478)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.example.EditBubbleView$2.onTouch(EditBubbleView.java:378)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7731)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2238)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7916)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4031)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3910)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3586)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3487)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3643)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3487)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5728)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5659)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5808)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can any one tell me how to resolve this. Thanks :)

Comment: Profile your application to see where it may have a memory leak.

Comment: Put your code where you got this crashed?

Comment: could you show code mentioned in error? `Square` and `EditBubbleView`

Comment: The stack trace shows that you are creating a BITMAP. What type of BITMAP are you creating and how big is it? Might exceed the memory available on your device.

Comment: @GarySchreiner I am adding the square on an image which user selects from the gallery. and the bitmap I am creating is the size of that image. Is that a problem in any ways?

Comment: Make your Bitmap variable as global. Also in your manifest set largeHeap value to true. If still the issue persists, then do sampling.

Comment: @SimplePlan and akhilless those two classes are quite big

Comment: @Droider I don't see that as inherently causing you to have an OutOfMemory exception. Sounds like something in your code is leaky or continually running/race condition and generating a large image in memory. Hard to say without seeing the code that's causing the Exception. I agree using largeHeap is bad unless you definitely know you need it and nothing else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this to your `manifest.xml` file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: That may work but would likely just hide the issue. Better to profile and test first to make sure it's needed.

Comment: the docs also warn that it is necessary to understand whether you app really needs largeHeap

Comment: this will be my last resort

Comment: @Droider http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html. **Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory** and you need a quick fix—you should use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained.

Answer (score 1):

It is the case of memory leak. First of all check out your code at these two

```
at com.example.Square.isClicked(Square.java:478)05-09 11:32:49.488: E/AndroidRuntime(24826):    
at com.example.EditBubbleView$2.onTouch(EditBubbleView.java:378)
```

Whether these two method are getting called and same time???? and if possible then paste your code over here so that we can have a look on that.